# Multiple errors while upgarding web application IE9 browser

Tags: arrays, date, constants, undefined, redeclaration

Multiple errors while upgrading web application IE9 browser:

```
1. SCRIPT5009: 'Date' is undefined 
2. SCRIPT5009: 'Array' is undefined 
3. SCRIPT5039: Redeclaration of const property
4. SCRIPT5009: 'jQuery' is undefined 
5. SCRIPT5009: '$' is undefined
```

We have external application which is upgraded from version 1.7.1  to version 2.1.0.   Inside this external form we have iframe, inside which our application screens load, and our application is using, jquery-1.8.3.js.

Can anyone help us this issue, why we are encountering with the above issue, while we are upgrading to IE9.
 The same above application is working absolutely correct on IE11 browser.

Comment: how are we supposed to help when we dont see any code?